# Using PHP to reload a page with new div content

Tags: php, html

I have a page that has main content and a menu bar, when a user logs in a $_SESSION variable is set via data pulled from a database to determine which main content and which menu bar the user sees.

The main page is along the lines of:

```
 <div id="menu">
    <?php include_once '/files/'.$_SESSION['menu']; ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php include_once '/files/'.$_SESSION['content']; ?>
    </div>
```

When the user logs in the $_SESSION  variables are set to "menu1.php" and "content1.php" or "menu2.php" and "content2.php", this works fine and the page loads correctly.

I have then included two buttons on the both menu bars as such:

```
  <form action='' method='POST'>
      <button type="submit" name="set1">Set 1</button>
    </form>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
      <button type="submit" name="set2">Set 2</i></button>
    </form>
```

And two "functions":

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['set2'])){
            unset($_SESSION['menu']);
            unset($_SESSION['content']);
            $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu2.php';
            $_SESSION['content'] = 'content2.php';
      };
      if(isset($_POST['set1'])){
            unset($_SESSION['menu']);
            unset($_SESSION['content']);
            $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu1.php';
            $_SESSION['content'] = 'conent1.php';
      };
     ?>
```

If you were to click the button to change the content and menu from 1 to 2, the page reloads with the correct content being shown "content2", however, the menu bar remains at "menu1", if you were to refresh the page only then does the menu change to "menu2", it's as if the menu session is one refresh behind. This occurs vice versa from 2 to 1.

What can be done so that when the page reloads, it reloads with both the new content and the new menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that $_SESSION variables sometimes require a page change, not just a refresh.

So in the action of the form where the button is I created a new php page containing the two php functions and then a header() to relocate me back to the home page:

```
<form action='changeContent.php' method='POST'>
  <button type="submit" name="set1">Set 1</button>
</form>
<form action='changeContent.php' method='POST'>
  <button type="submit" name="set2">Set 2</i></button>
</form>
```

the action now directs me to changeContent.php and on that page I have the fucntions:

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['set2'])){
        $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu2.php';
        $_SESSION['content'] = 'content2.php';
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  };
  if(isset($_POST['set1'])){
        $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu1.php';
        $_SESSION['content'] = 'conent1.php';
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  };
 ?>
```

Now when the button is clicked you are redirected to the page and the content is fully changed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never use something like:

```
<?php include_once '/files/'.$_SESSION['menu']; ?>
```

It is a huge vulnerability, read more - [OWASP XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). If you, for some reason, can't use any other solution then use:

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['menu'] == 'menu2.php') include_once '/files/menu2.php'; 
?>
```

And for your question - try to use the following code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['set2'])){
        $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu2.php';
        $_SESSION['content'] = 'content2.php';
        session_write_close();
  };
  if(isset($_POST['set1'])){
        $_SESSION['menu'] = 'menu1.php';
        $_SESSION['content'] = 'conent1.php';
        session_write_close();
  };
 ?>
```

You can also test it with 1-second delay:

```
header('Refresh: 1; URL=/');
```

Comment: Thanks for the security tips. Will definitely adjust.

The Solution didn't work though, same result.
Adding in the periodic refresh just shows the menu bar loading only after one refresh, besides the reload from the form submission.

I am echoing the session variable, for debug purposes, into each div, the main content div shows the updated session variable, but the menu div only "updates" the session variable after another page reload, after the one from the form submission

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on this page?

Comment: I do, initially there is a login page, that when login is succesful, sets session variables and directs you to the home page. ```elseif ($pwdCheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['content'] = $row['user_home'];
          $_SESSION['menu'] = $row['user_menu'];
          header("Location: ../../home.php");
          exit();```

Then there is another ```session_start()``` atop the home page, the home page is the page I described above with the ```includes```

Comment: And what about `menu1.php` and `content1.php`? Can you try to add it there too?
I think you have something in `content1.php` that you don't have in `menu1.php`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. I managed to resolve the issue, will post how in an answer